# How to parse string to an array using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I am a getting a `JSON` response from an external Api:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "data": {
    "Response": "R00=03&R01=Invalid User",
    "TokenStatus": "Used"
  }
}
```

But I need to be able to parse the `data.Response` string to determine whether the request was successful. In case of success the string will be similar to:

> R00=00&R01=Balance Added. &R02=59.00&R03=1.00

in case of fail it will be similar to

> R00=03&R01=Invalid User

I need to parse it into a JS object like:

```
{
    "R00": "00",
    "R01": "Balance Added. ",
    "R02": "59.00",
    "R03": "1.00"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to parse the JSON into a Javascript object, or do you want to test `data.response` value ?

Comment: How has the statusCode anything to do with the way you parse the `data.response` value?

Comment: @mega6382 Thanks, but your question is about parsing the `data.response` field; not handling API failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's URL-encoded, so let's try the [query string parser](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/querystring.html).

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

querystring.decode(data.Response)
// { R00: '03', R01: 'Invalid User' }
```

Comment: Is `require('querystring')` available by default on **AWS Lambda**?

Comment: `querystring` is a core module, it's likely that you can use it without requiring it first.

Comment: Works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a):

```js
var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "data": {
        "Response": "R00=00&R01=Balance Added. &R02=59.00&R03=1.00",
        "TokenStatus": "Used"
    }
};
var retVal = response.data.Response.split('&').reduce(function(acc, ele) {
    var x = ele.split('=');
    acc[x[0]] = x[1];
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(retVal);
```

Comment: I was going to write it ! Nice one :)

Comment: This is flawed because it fails when the value contains an unencoded `=` (this is legal in URL encoding) and it does not URL-decode the values either. And once you do all that it's easier to just use the built-in module.

Answer (score 1):

You can wether look for the substring `R01=Balance Added.` in your response:

```
data.Response.indexOf('R01=Balance Added.') > 0
```

Or if you want to parse the Response to use it for other purpose, I would suggest to use querystring module built in node.js

```
var object = querystring.decode(data.Response);
// object will look like this { R00: '03', R01: 'Invalid User' }
```